# In Pokemon Go gym battles, how are Power, Energy, and DPS related?

Tags: pokemon-go

In short, how is Power related to Energy and DPS and why does it matter?

It seems that Energy is quite simple: fast moves charge up energy level, while charge moves require a certain energy level. Then, once you use that charge move, it will deplete that much energy. (Example, Hydro Pump requires 100% Energy level, while Dragon Pulse requires 50%).

And DPS or DPS with STAB (same type attack bonus) can be quite simple: it is how much damage that can be done to the HP of the other Pokemon. (probably with the type effectiveness and the relative CP or IV of the two battling Pokemons considered.)

So what is Power? One example is for [Marowak](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/marowak.html), with Dig listed as 70, and it required 33% of full energy, so it looks more powerful than Earthquake, which has power of 100 but requires 100% of full energy level. (Dig's 70 x 3 = 210, while Earthquake's 100 x 1 = 100, so Dig seems to be more "powerful"?) But Earthquake's DPS with STAB is actually double that of Dig (29.8 vs 15.1)... so how does the 70 relate to Energy or DPS? (or what is the meaing of this Power number?)

Answer (score 3):

Power is correlated to how much damage a move does. Energy has no relation to how effective a move is, though stronger moves tend to require more energy. (20% for 15 Power Twister, 100% for 100 Power Earthquake, etc.)

DPS (Damage Per Second) is based on how much damage is dealt over ***how long*** the move actually takes. Dig is a long move, so the DPS suffers, while Earthquake is quicker and does more base damage to begin with, so DPS is much higher.

Dig, being 70 Power, takes 5.8 seconds to complete. 70/5.8 is roughly 12.1. Earthquake, on the other hand, takes barely over 4 seconds, but has 100 Power. 100/4.2 is roughly 23.8. This is why despite having only a difference in Power of 30, the DPS of Earthquake is double that of Dig.

The reason Earthquake, Hyper Beam, Blizzard, Solar Beam, etc. are effective is that they are a fast, hard hit. Dig would take much longer to do as much damage as the others. The time you spend performing Dig is time that you would have been able to spend doing your fast attack, had you used Earthquake.